# Unable to call Azure DevOps Rest Api through PAT token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to import json file saved in local directory (desktop) to Azure DevOps Library Variable Group using Azure DevOps Rest api.

This is the script.

```
$jsonbody = Get-Content -Path "C:\variable\1.json" | Out-String
# Define organization name and PAT
$organization = ""
$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $jsonbody -ContentType application/json
```

This is the error message that I receive.

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401)
> Unauthorized. At line:6 char:1 + Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method
> Post -Headers $head -Body $jsonbo ... +
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
> WebException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
> ```

I tried different rest api but received the same error message.

```
    $jsonbody = Get-Content -Path "C:\variable\1.json" | Out-String
    # Define organization name and PAT
    $organization = ""
    $token = "{PAT}"
    $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
    $url="https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/projects?api-version=7.1-preview.4"
    $head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $head -ContentType application/json
```

**PAT token has full access.**

These are the documents that I followed.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

I can use the same PAT token to publish packages to Azure DevOps artefact feed (Nuget and NPM).

Any help would be appreciated on why the PAT token is not working when using rest api.

Comment: Your example is working. Check the `{PAT}` content.... maybe there are copy/paste issues.. 401 says you can not log in to the system, 403 is a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I generated PAT token with **Full Access** in my DevOps Portal like this:

[image]

Now, I ran below PowerShell script to **list projects** by calling Azure DevOps Rest API through PAT token:

```
$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/org_name"
$pat = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$queryString = "api-version=7.1-preview.4"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
$header = @{Authorization = "Basic $token"}

$projectsUrl = "$orgUrl/_apis/projects?$queryString"
$projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
$projects.value | ConvertTo-Json
```

**Response:**

[image]

Similarly, you can use below script to import Json file saved in local directory to Azure DevOps Library Variable Group using Azure DevOps Rest Api:

```
$jsonbody = Get-Content -Path "C:\variables\var.json" | Out-String
$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/org_name"
$pat = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$queryString = "api-version=7.1-preview.2"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
$header = @{Authorization = "Basic $token"}

$Url = "$orgUrl/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?$queryString"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Post -Body $jsonbody -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

$result.variableGroupProjectReferences
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Azure DevOps portal where variable group imported successfully like this:

[image]

If still the error persists, try creating new PAT token with **Full Access** and use above mentioned scripts to call DevOps REST API.

**Reference:**
[How to call Azure Devops REST API from PowerShell (opentechguides.com)](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/azure/201/devops-rest-powershell.html)

Answer (score 0):

> PAT token has full access.

Could you double-check if your PAT has full access?
<del>You can use [PAT-Get-REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to get the value of `scope`</del>.
You can follow the document 1 you mentioned above to check the Scopes in Azure Devops page.

Besides you can create a new PAT with custom defined scopes and then try to use the new PAT to invoke REST APIS.

Authorize the scope of access associated with this token.

example:

```
// Read, write, & manage
vso.variablegroups_manage  
vso.profile
vso.project
```

From looking at your code,

```
 $token = "{PAT}"
 $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
```

Could you remove the curly braces `{}` and try again?

```
$token = "PAT"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$token"))
```

Hope it can help you.

**UPDATE**

After confirming with PG, [this set of APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) will not work with PAT. These APIs require OAuth (which in turn means they'll need to setup an AAD app and register it with DevOps and all that fun stuff).
For more information, please refer to [Manage personal access tokens (PATs) using REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops#authenticate-with-microsoft-entra-tokens)

But back your case, i want to confirm with you if you can invoke variablegroups or Projects REST API with your PAT in postman. From looking at the error information `WebCmdletWebResponseException.xxx.InvokeRestMethodCommand`, it seems like an  PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest issue.

Please test these REST APIs in postman to verify that this is not an issue with PowerShell.

Comment: Hi @Dou Xu-MSFT, the PAT has full access. I tried to get the scope by following the url for Get Rest Pat API you sent in postman, and received the following error.

Error - 203 Non-authoritative Information. Microsoft Internet Explorer&#39;s Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator.